# Repository cache refresh failed + pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I am using pentaho ,
my application works fine one day but the next suddenly my folders wouldn't load and display in user console and when i try to refresh error msg comes in a pop saying

```
**"repository cache refresh failed "**
```

Comment: You might want to try looking in your tomcat's webserver logs. Pentaho sometimes logs a more descriptive error or a stacktrace which might help us solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if MySQL database for Pentaho is online.